# Не всегда проходит авторизация через гугл аккаунт в приложении

Tags: java, android, авторизация, google-api, oauth

Делаю приложение шагомер используя `googleFit Api`. При первом входе в программу работает авторизация через гугл аккаунт. На десятерых устройствах все работает отлично, но еще на одном проблема с аутентификацией. Несколько раз на нем авторизация проходила с первого раза, но как правило, когда пользователь выбирает свой аккаунт, `startResolutionForResult` возвращает 0 (вместо -1). Что в нем происходит и можно ли это вылечить? На всякий случай вот код создания `GoogleApiClient`

```
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(Client.this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(Client.this)
            .build();
```

И сама реализация `OnConnectionFailed`

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull final ConnectionResult result) {
    isClientConnected = false;

    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), MainActivity.getActivity(), 0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!authInProgress) {
        try {
            authInProgress = true;
            result.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.getActivity(), Constants.REQUEST_OAUTH_FLAG);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Ну, а уже в `onActivityResult` в переменной `resultCode` приходит 0.
Акцентирую снова внимание, что проблема выявилась пока на одном устройстве.
Подскажите пожалуйста, если есть мысли по этому поводу.

Comment: ну код выглядит правдоподобно, а на каком устройстве не работает?

Comment: Решено! По всей видимости была не корректная сборка студии (может какой-нибудь плагин не установлен). После сборки на другом компьютере все работает корректно.